# Birational invariant Hodge numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

Consider the Hodge numbers of smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb C$. I am aware of the fact that only the outer Hodge numbers (essentially $h^{p,0}$) are invariant under birational equivalence. I would like to know whether there will be more invariances if we have some additional conditions. More precisely, say $X$ and $Y$ are birational equivalence via some rational map $f: X\dashrightarrow Y$, and we moreover assume that

> the birational map $f$ can be defined on a larger open set such that the complement has some higher codimension $d$,

or

> both $X$ and $Y$ are fiber bundles over some curve $T$ and the rational map $f: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is an isomorphism of fiber bundles over some open subset of $T$,

then, will there be more birational invariances?

The only example I know of non-birationally-invariant Hodge numbers comes from blow-up, and I guess basically this is the only reason. From this, I believe the answer would be quite positive. But I do not know how to prove it.

Any references would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the codimension of the subvariety you blowup dictates how many Hodge numbers change.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for this. It looks like to be true, but could you give a reference for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know a reference. It was just a conversation I had with a friend.

Comment: You can find formulas for how cohomology changes when you blow up along a smooth center. I think this would be in any book on complex geometry. Or try to prove it yourself using Mayer-Vietoris. You’ll see that the cohomology only changes in certain codimension so you get invariance of some cohomology (and thus of some Hodge numbers).

Comment: @SamirCanning Thanks! I followed this and posted the result as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to show if one blows up a smooth subvariety of dimension $d$, then only the $H^{p,q}$ with $|p-q|\leq d$ will be changed. Together with the weak factorization theorem, it proves the first statement we want.